# Php check if digit time is greater than other digit time

Tags: php, time, foreach, explode, implode

I have an array of digit time numbers (I get them from the input fields).

Here are a few examples:

```
00:00:10
00:03:00
01:20:00
```

My question is following, how do I check if a digit time is greater than another?

Following function works up to

> 00:01:00

After that I get an error.

```
$inputTimes = $request->input('times', []);

foreach ($inputTimes as $inputKey => $inputValue)
{
    $Input = new Input();
    $Input->input_start = $inputValue['input_start'];

    $tInput     = explode(':', $inputValue['input_timelapse']);
    $implInput  = implode('', $tInput);
    $iImplInput = (int)$implInput;

    // Check if time is greater
    if($iImplInput > $iVideoDuration)
    {
    .. error time greater
    }
}
```

Comment: Minute - 60 seconds, Hour - 3600 seconds.

Comment: @u_mulder so you suggest to convert the digit time to seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I would convert it to Unix time by using the inbuild `strtotime()` function.

For example: 
`strtotime('01:20:00');` will output *1483492800* while `strtotime('00:01:00');` will output *1483488060*.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks I will try that out soon, do you think that this also works with times like this: 0:01:00.003290?

Comment: No. Unix time uses whole seconds. Goodluck - make sure to accept my answer if it fixes your problem.